# Not getting accurate result when using normalized data for gradient descent

Tags: machine-learning, octave, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I am currently on week 2 of Andrew NG's Machine Learning course on Coursera, and I came across an issue that I cannot sort out.

Based on a data set, where the first column is the house size, the second the number of bedrooms in it, and the third column is the price of it, I need to use linear regression and gradient descent after normalizing the data to predict new house prices.

However, I am getting a gigantic number for my prediction and I cannot find where is the error on my calculations.

I am using the following:

```
alpha = 0.03;
num_iters = 400;
```

**Code to normalize the features (X is the data set matrix):**

```
X_norm = X;
mu = zeros(1, size(X, 2));
sigma = zeros(1, size(X, 2));

for i = 1:size(X, 2);

  mu(1, i) = mean(X(:, i)),    % Getting the mean of each row.
  sigma(1, i) = std(X(:, i)),  % Getting the standard deviation of each row.

  for j = 1:size(X, 1);

    X_norm(j, i) = (X(j, i) .- mu(1, i)) ./ sigma(1, i);

  end;
end;
```

**Code to calculate current cost:**

```
m = length(y);
J = 0;        
predictions = X * theta;
sqErrors = (predictions - y).^2;
J = (1/(2*m)) * sum(sqErrors);
```

**Code to calculate gradient descent:**

```
m = length(y); % number of training examples
J_history = zeros(num_iters, 1);

for iter = 1:num_iters

  % Getting the predictions for our firstly chosen theta values.
  predictions = X * theta;

  % Getting the error difference of the hypothesis(h(x)) and real results(y).
  diff = predictions - y;

  % Getting the number of features.
  features_num = size(X, 2);  

  % Applying gradient descent for each feature.
  for i = 1:features_num;

    theta(i, 1) = theta(i, 1) - (alpha / m) * sum(diff .* X(:, i))

  end;

  % Saving the cost J in every iteration    
  J_history(iter) = computeCostMulti(X, y, theta);
```

**The resulting price I am getting when predicting a house with 1650 squared feet and 3 bedrooms:**
182329818.366117

Comment: Do you normalize test data? If you normalize training set, you should apply the same transformation on your test data as well. Giving a large number to an estimator which is trained on small range might be the reason for such large result.

Comment: That was the issue. Thank you very much.